# android-lockpattern library comparison fails

Tags: android

I am trying to implemet some security within my appliccation using the lock pattern library

i have followed every step here https://code.google.com/p/android-lockpattern/wiki/QuickUse
and for some reason my code [below] triggers the `LockPatternActivity.RESULT_FAILED`
All the `LockPatternActivity` intents are functioning correctly

```
public void buttonClick() {

    _prefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    String restoredText = _prefs.getString("pattern", null);

    if(restoredText== null)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(LockPatternActivity.ACTION_CREATE_PATTERN, null, this, LockPatternActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQ_CREATE_PATTERN);
    }
    else
    {
        char[] savedPattern = restoredText.toCharArray();

        Intent intent = new Intent(LockPatternActivity.ACTION_COMPARE_PATTERN, null,
                this, LockPatternActivity.class);

        intent.putExtra(LockPatternActivity.EXTRA_PATTERN, savedPattern);
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQ_ENTER_PATTERN);
    }
}


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int request, int result, Intent data) {

    char[] pattern = data.getCharArrayExtra(LockPatternActivity.EXTRA_PATTERN);

    if (request == REQ_CREATE_PATTERN) {
        if (result == RESULT_OK) {
            editor.putString("pattern", pattern.toString());
            editor.apply();
        }

    } else if (request == REQ_ENTER_PATTERN) {
        switch (result) {
            case RESULT_OK:
                break;
            case RESULT_CANCELED:
                // The user cancelled the task
                break;
            case LockPatternActivity.RESULT_FAILED:
                // The user failed to enter the pattern
                break;
            case LockPatternActivity.RESULT_FORGOT_PATTERN:
                // The user forgot the pattern and invoked your recovery Activity.
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `RESULT_FAILED` is returned for `if` case or `else` case or both?

Comment: it  returned for `else`

Comment: The only reason for that can be that your `savedPattern` is not correct. Are you sure you have saved a pattern correctly before going to else.. its trying to compare the saved pattern with the pattern you have drawn and they don't match

Answer (score 0):

Replace this line editor.putString("pattern", pattern.toString()); to editor.putString("pattern",  new String(pattern));

Answer (score 0):

Android-lockpattern has been stopped. You might want to try [this](https://github.com/asghonim/simple_android_lock_pattern) library instead. It allows you to use lock pattern inside your own activity instead of in it's own activity. Hope it helps!